# Numbered images selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day!

First of all, I don't what is the right name or title for my question but that's what I think what I needed.

how can I make an image selector with numbered function like the image below? I am using html and jquery to select images but I don't know how to put and ordered numbers when selecting an images. My codes are like...

HTML:

```
<div class="photoList">
  <label class="singlePhotoWrap relative">
    <img src="images/previewDefaultImg.png" class="photo" alt="Image">
    <img src="images/numberedIco.png" class="absolute numberedIcon" alt="Check Icon">
    <span class="photoCounter">1</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="photoSelector" class="hidden" autocomplete="off">
  </label>
  ...
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$(".singlePhotoWrap").click(function() {
    var current = document.getElementById("photoSelectedCounter").value;

    if ($(this).find('input[name=photoSelector]:checked')){
    var totalAdd = parseFloat(current) + .5;
    $('#photoSelectedCounter').val(totalAdd);
    $(this).find(".photoCounter").text(totalAdd);
    }
    if ($(this).find('input[name=photoSelector]:unchecked')) {
        var totalAdd = parseFloat(current) - .5;
        $('#photoSelectedCounter').val(totalAdd);
        $(this).find(".photoCounter").text(totalAdd);
    }
});
```

});

My javascript codes always returning as checked. It always adding to my span.

Here's the screenshot:

*Numbered Image Selector Screenshot*
[image: Numbered Image Selector Screenshot]

How can I do that using javascript or jquery?

Comment: can you please provide the javascript that you already have?

Comment: Javascript added.

Comment: Your `if` statements (as they're written) don't serve a purpose. [Wrapping a jquery `.find()` in an `if` statement will **always** return `true`.](http://jsfiddle.net/gxctqj8p/) If you're trying to check if such an element *exists*, you need to use **`.length`**:  `if ($("this").find(".x").length) { //it exists }`

Comment: Thanks Man! It worked.